# How to reverse the order of dates in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm programming in Kotlin and using Firebase as DB.

My aim is to write all the dates and their respective content in a listView however it has to be from the most recent to the oldest date.

In the image is an arrow showing which date should appear first

TY for your time

[image]

There is the code that read the input and send data to DB

```
            val numeroOrigem = binding.meuNumero.text.toString()
            val numeroDestino = binding.editTextNumber2.text.toString()
            val saldo = binding.editTextNumberDecimal2.text.toString()

            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Historico")
            val data = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sss'Z'")
            val currentDate = data.format(Date())
            val DataTransfer = DataTransfer(numeroOrigem,numeroDestino ,saldo)
            database.child(numeroOrigem).child(currentDate).setValue(DataTransfer)
```

Comment: So you want that order to be seen in the console or in your app's code?

Comment: Have a look at the questions I linked and more from this list: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bandroid%5D+descending